# Joomla 3 возвращает "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: joomla

Когда открытие сайта показывается пустую страницу, в консоле возвращает "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: Ну, Джумла упала из-за внутренней ошибки. Это может быть что угодно.

Comment: Проверьте лог Вашего сайта - там должна быть информация почему так случилось.

Comment: Приведите содрежимое журнала ошибок вашего веб-сервера. Если у вас Apache - то это (скорее всего) файл /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log. Если этого файла нет, то посмотрите в конфигурационном файле веб-сервера чему равна директива ErrorLog и приведите содрежимое указанного в ней файла.

Comment: Так же Joomla может показывать ошибку 500, которая не является настоящей ошибкой 500 - в том смысле что вернёт её сама CMS, а не веб-сервер. В таком случае нужно глядеть журнал ошибок самой Jooml'ы. Так что проверьте так же и файлы в каталоге logs вашего сайта.